# Passing SQL Query data into HTML Form with Flask - Truncated String

Tags: html, sql, forms, flask

I am having an issue with my strings getting truncated when Passing SQL Query data into HTML Form Input Box with Flask. The HTML & Jinja is shown below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dinner" value={{ dinner_info[0]['dinner_name'] }}>
```

On the webpage, outside of the HTML form input box, the whole string will be show as 'Green Chicken'

However, inside the HTML form input box, the string is truncated to just 'Green'

Screenshot:
[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: Hi @GreyLi, I put the screenshot above. If you look in the form Input Box, it says 'Butter', however, if you look at the test below the 'Submit Dinners' button, it shows 'Butter Chicken'. They are both pulling from the same SQL query datapoint.

Comment: It's a bit weird, can you post the full template code and print the value of `dinner_info`?